# Xcode 6 beta 6 init

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, init

When trying to initialize an instance of my class at runtime the App seems to freeze and not continue, here is where:

```
class Game: NSObject {
    var allies: DoubleLinkedList<Combatant>
    var enemys: DoubleLinkedList<Combatant>
    var everyone: DoubleLinkedList<Combatant>
    override init() {
    println("Init of game")
        allies = DoubleLinkedList<Combatant>()
        enemys = DoubleLinkedList<Combatant>()
        everyone = DoubleLinkedList<Combatant>()
        println("Lists Made")
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Here is the init of DoubleLinkedList:

```
class DoubleLinkedList<T: NSObject>: Printable {
    var first: Node<T>?
    var last: Node<T>?
    var description: String {
        return "Double linked list with ? objects."
    }
    init() {
        println("Init of DoubleLinkedList")
    }
}
```

There is some mode code but I don't think it would be related. The console will print this:

```
Init of game
```

I put a breakpoint on `allies = DoubleLinkedList<Combatant>()`, the app paused as expected. after "Continue Program Execution" nothing else seems to happen. I assume this is one of the weird semantic bugs with the swift beta release and may have a workaround.

I have cleaned the build and build folder, also I have remove the DerivedData folder already.

Comment: Try letting the code run and use the debugger to pause the app and take a look at what the main thread is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue in XCode6 Beta6. More details here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1030581

Comment: Thanks! Generic support does not seem to be working well in swift. Hopefully the issue is resolved soon!